# How do I make grouped boxplots work in plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'd like to make a grouped boxplot in plotly in R, but it simply doesn't show up

I'm taking a boxplot that works in ggplot and trying to translate it to r

This is my code

```
library(fpp)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(Hmisc)
gg <-
credit %>% 
  ggplot(aes(score,
             group = cut2(savings, g = 4),
             fill = cut2(savings, g = 4))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
ggplotly(gg)
```

It shows up really nicely in ggplot and then doesn't show at all in plotly

Comment: What if you just used `plotly` code more specifically? `plotly::plot_ly(iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Species, type = "box")`

Comment: That works great and that's what I'll do